# Normalize stylesheet with Twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, normalize

I'm just starting a project which I'm using Twitters Bootstrap for and was wondering if it has its own reset rules.

Normally I plonk in a normalize stylesheet to help my sites look more consistent cross browser  but is this required with Bootstrap?

Comment: it use [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Bootstrap already uses [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/). Take a look at [the source](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css) (and the [LESS file](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/reset.less)):

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v2.2.2
 *
 * Copyright 2012 Twitter, Inc
 * Licensed under the Apache License v2.0
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Designed and built with all the love in the world @twitter by @mdo and @fat.
 */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap v3 now makes this explicit and also includes the version number:

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.0.3 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2013 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 */

/*! normalize.css v2.1.3 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}
```

Note that normalize.css is now at v3.0.0-rc.1 so you may want to look at the CHANGELOG or diff and evaluate whether you'd like to use them on your site.